# How to mock MyBatis mapper interface?

Tags: java, junit, jersey, mockito, mybatis

I am writing unit test for my Jersey rest API which uses MyBatis at the background.

This is the structure of my classes:

**rest service:**

```
@Path("/api")
public class HelloRestService {
    @Inject
    HelloBean helloBean;

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{name}")
    public Response echo(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(helloBean.sayHello(name)).build();
    }
}
```

**Stateless EJB:**

```
@Stateless
public class HelloStatelessBean implements HelloBean {
    // Injected MyBatis mapper (dao)
    @Inject
    private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(final Long id) {
        return employeeMapper.getEmployeeById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return employeeMapper.getAllEmployee();
    }

    /**
     * Echo.
     */
    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s! This is Ejb :)", name);
    }
}
```

**MyBatis mapper interface:**

```
@Dependent
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
    @Select("select * from EMPLOYEE where id = #{id}")
    Employee getEmployeeById(Long id);

    @Select("select * from EMPLOYEE")
    ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployee();
}
```

I have a nice junit test for testing my MyBatis mapper. It works fine. The next step is that I would like to write a test for my jersey rest class. This is what I have:

```
public class HelloRestServiceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        return new ResourceConfig(HelloRestService.class) {
            {
                register(new HelloStatelessBean());
                register(Mockito.mock(EmployeeMapper.class));
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void echo() throws Exception {
        Response response = target("/api/echo/John").request().get();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertNotNull(response.getEntity());
    }
}
```

But this test throws an exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider a.b.HelloStatelessBean registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider a.b.HelloStatelessBean will be ignored. 
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider a.b.EmployeeMapper$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ee86c913 registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider a.b.EmployeeMapper$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ee86c913 will be ignored.
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=EmployeeMapper,parent=HelloStatelessBean,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,52451302)
MultiException stack 1 of 1
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=EmployeeMapper,parent=HelloStatelessBean,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,52451302)
```

What is the proper way to mock MyBatis mapper with mockito?

---

UPDATE 1
EJB test works like a charm:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HelloStatelessBeanTest {

    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @Spy
    private HelloBean helloBean = new HelloStatelessBean();

    @Test
    public void sayHello() throws Exception {

        String actual = helloBean.sayHello("Pear");
        System.out.println(actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeeById() {
        // create an SqlSessionFactory
        try (Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-configuration.xml")) {

            sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
            SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
            EmployeeMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);
            Employee employee = mapper.getEmployeeById(1l);
            Assert.assertNotNull(employee);
            Assert.assertNotNull(employee.getId());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**But it does not work with jersey. I have tried it this way, but I get same exception then before:**

```
public class HelloRestServiceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        return new ResourceConfig(HelloRestService.class) {
            {
                 try (Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("configuration.xml")) {
                     SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
                     SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
                     EmployeeMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);

                     register(new HelloStatelessBean());
                     register(mapper, EmployeeMapper.class);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void echo() throws Exception {
        Response response = target("/api/echo/Arnold").request().get();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertNotNull(response.getEntity());
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you test just  from EJB? If you replace injected `EmployeeMapper `with a concrete type stubbing interface? then if this stub is mocked? What changes if `@Dependent`is removed? I seems the mapper implementation instantiated by the container has something the container needs and is not present in the proxy built by Mockito.

Comment: Hi, I tried to remove @Dependent annotation. It does not help. I created an implementation of the Mapper interface and tried to mock it. Same exception. Please check my update.

Comment: `HelloStatelessBeanTest` does not test anything, the code is the same as the implementation. The RestService class you want to test depends on EJB, why not mocking this EJB (as you want to test the controller calls EJB and returns a value based on what the EJB returns)? Same for EJB testing could mock mapper. How does that behave?

Comment: I would like to test together the rest + EJB because rest HTTP response really depends on EJB. I would like to mock the database layer but I do not want to mock EJB. Why? I want to check the result of the rest api. Do not be confused by HelloStatelessBeanTest.testGetEmployeeById method. That will be deleted if I have a working test for rest class.

Comment: I am going to update my code during the weekend according to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728129/how-to-mock-mybatis-mapper-interface-with-arquillian-part2. I think it will solve this.